# Get feed from Age Gated Instagram account

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We are working on a project for our client which is an Alcoholic Brand. We are trying to get image feed via https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user_id}/media/recent/?client_id={client_id} but we get an APIAgeGatedError. We think this is related to Alcoholic advertising in the account. Is there any way to get a feed from this account?

Thanks in advance.